# Azure MS Graph Claim Mapping Policy Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am a little confused with the MS Graph article[Vague] related to Claim Mapping Policy. I am trying to create claims using PowerShell. used below format to create new claims map getting error
**New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy : Property definition has an invalid value.**

Help is needed Here!!!

```
    $policymap=[ordered]@{
definition=@(
@"
{
    "claimsMappingPolicy" :
        {
            "claimsSchema":[
                {
                    "source":"user"
                    "id":"assignedrikes"
                    "samlclaimtype":"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role"
                },
                {
                    "source":"user"
                    "id":"assignedrikes"
                    "samlclaimtype":"https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/RoleSessionName"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
"@
)
displayname="Test"
isorganizationdefault=$false
}

New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy -BodyParameter $policymap
```

Answer (score 0):

> New claims map getting error **New-MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy**

This error may occur if you are using incorrect format *samlclaimtype* instead of using *MgPolicyClaimMappingPolicy,* make sure to ***install Azure AD Preview*** while running below script.

***Please check below few workarounds:***

I ***installed Azure AD Preview module*** and created claims using below script.

```
Connect-AzureAD
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/vikram","JwtClaimType":"vikram"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "vikram" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

**Result:**
[image]

Try to add service principal and check if it is succeeded or not.

For service principal ID, ***Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise Applications -> Your Web API -> object ID*** like below:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the Web API ServicePrincipal> -RefObjectId <ObjectId of the Policy>

Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id <ObjectId of the Web API ServicePrincipal>
```

[image]

To assign value to that claim, login to Microsoft [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) with your ***tenant admin account*** and run below script. ***This completes the development of your claims mapping successfully. ***

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me
```

```json
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "vedha"
    }
}
```

[image]

Now ***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Manifest*** to make your claims to accept as ***true*** like below:

[image]

Then, Go to ***Expose an API*** under *manage* edit your **Application ID URI** pattern like **`https://<yourTenantDomain>`** instead of default `api://<GUID>`, and save.

Generate access token and you can see that custom claim you created in the decoded token. To decode the token, you can use ***jwt.ms*** website