# Cannot find type [Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimsMappingPolicy] Error

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

Im trying to add additional claim mapping to an app registration, Ive created in my tenant.

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <obj-id>
$policy = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimsMappingPolicy

$policy.InputClaims = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.InputClaim).Type("email")
)
$policy.OutputClaims = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OutputClaim).Type("t24user")
)
$policy.ClaimMappings = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimMapping).InputClaimType("email").OutputClaimType("t24user").TransformationMethod("ExtractPrefixFromEmail")
)
```

Im getting the following error when I run this on line 2

`$policy = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimsMappingPolicy`

```
At line:1 char:11
+ $policy = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimsMap ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I tried to re-install **AzureAD** module and also tried with installing **AzureADPreivew** Module also. But it was not helping. Appreciate help here.

Comment: See if following helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519681/azure-ms-graph-claim-mapping-policy-powershell?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

When I ran same PowerShell script as you, I got **same error** like below:

```
$app = Get-AzureADApplication -ObjectId <obj-id>
$policy = New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimsMappingPolicy

$policy.InputClaims = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.InputClaim).Type("email")
)
$policy.OutputClaims = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.OutputClaim).Type("t24user")
)
$policy.ClaimMappings = @(
    (New-Object Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ClaimMapping).InputClaimType("email").OutputClaimType("t24user").TransformationMethod("ExtractPrefixFromEmail")
)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of **New-AzureADPolicy** command that requires `AzureADPreview` module.

To install that module, you need to uninstall `AzureAD` module like below:

```
Disconnect-AzureAD
Uninstall-Module AzureAD
Install-Module AzureADPreview
Connect-AzureAD
```

[image]

Now run below Powershell command to create claim mapping policy:

```
New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('
{
    "ClaimsMappingPolicy":
    {
        "Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", 
        "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"extensionattribute1","SamlClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/t24user","JwtClaimType":"t24user"}]
    }
}') -DisplayName "t24userclaimPolicy" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
```

[image]

Note the  **`ID`**  of the policy from above response and assign it to your service principal using below command:

```
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID -RefObjectId policy_ID
```

To **confirm** whether the policy is assigned or not, you can run below command:

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id serviceprincipal_ObjectID
```

**Response:**

[image]

I assigned **value** to above claim by running this Graph query:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
{
"onPremisesExtensionAttributes": 
    {
        "extensionAttribute1": "sri_mail"
    }
}
```

[image]

Make sure to set  **`"acceptMappedClaims": true`**  in App's Manifest like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> Your App -> Manifest***

[image]

Now, I generated **token** for above application and got claim successfully after decoding it in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/) website like below:

[image]